# How to properly format JSON in ASP.Net Core 2.0 it has missing curly braces in JSON result

Tags: json, asp.net-core

Please help me what is the problem with my code:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ModelID,ConductionSticker,Vin,EngineNumber,Cost,Date,Description,RowVersion")] Vehicle vehicle)
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        using (var transaction = await _context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync())
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(vehicle.ConductionSticker))
                    {
                        vehicle.ConductionSticker = Regex.Replace(vehicle.ConductionSticker, @"[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", String.Empty).Replace(" ", String.Empty);
                        if (await _context.Vehicles.CountAsync(v => v.ConductionSticker == vehicle.ConductionSticker) > 0)
                        {
                            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Conduction sticker already exists");
                            return BadRequest(ModelState);
                        }
                    }

                    vehicle.Vin = Regex.Replace(vehicle.Vin, @"[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", String.Empty).Replace(" ", String.Empty);
                    if (await _context.Vehicles.CountAsync(v => v.Vin == vehicle.Vin) > 0)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", "VIN already exists");
                        return BadRequest(ModelState);
                    }

                    vehicle.EngineNumber = Regex.Replace(vehicle.EngineNumber, @"[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", String.Empty).Replace(" ", String.Empty);
                    if (await _context.Vehicles.CountAsync(v => v.EngineNumber == vehicle.EngineNumber) > 0)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Engine No. already exists");
                        return BadRequest(ModelState);
                    }

                    await _context.Vehicles.AddAsync(vehicle);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                    var vehicleCurrentPlate = new VehicleCurrentPlate()
                    {
                        VehicleID = vehicle.ID
                    };

                    await _context.VehicleCurrentPlates.AddAsync(vehicleCurrentPlate);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                    transaction.Commit();

                    vehicle.CurrentPlate = null;

                    return Ok(vehicle);
                }
                else
                {
                    return BadRequest(ModelState);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while saving vehicle");
                transaction.Rollback();
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Something went wrong please try again. If the error persists please contact the administrator.");
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
        }
    }


    public class Vehicle
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ModelID { get; set; }
    public VehicleModel Model { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Vin { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string EngineNumber { get; set; }
    [StringLength(7)]
    public string ConductionSticker { get; set; }
    [StringLength(500)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Range(0, 999999999.99)]
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    [StringLength(60)]
    public string ProfilePicture { get; set; }
    public VehicleCurrentPlate CurrentPlate { get; set; }
    public ICollection<VehicleAccessory> Accessories { get; set; }
    public ICollection<VehiclePlate> Plates { get; set; }
    public ICollection<VehicleInsurance> Insurance { get; set; }


    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}
```

`return Ok(vehicle)` result:

```
{"id":34052,"modelID":1,"model":null,"vin":"xxx","engineNumber":"xxx","conductionSticker":"xxx","description":null,"cost":1.00,"date":"2010-10-10T00:00:00","profilePicture":null,"currentPlate":{"id":34051,"vehicleID":34052
```

There are some missing curly braces in json result. How could I fix this?

Comment: please don't mind the `vehicle.CurrentPlate = null;` code that is my solution to get a successful json result {"id":34052,"modelID":1,"model":null,"vin":"xxx","engineNumber":"xxx","conductionSticker":"xxx","description":null,"cost":1.00,"date":"2010-10-10T00:00:00","profilePicture":null,"currentPlate":null}

Comment: That's simply not possible. For the JSON produced by `OkResult` to be invalid would imply that ASP.NET Core itself is fundamentally broken, and *every other developer* out there using ASP.NET Core would also be experiencing this, which is simply not the case. There's something else going on, not included in what you've chosen to post here. Perhaps something client-side?

Comment: Json(vehicle) and Ok(vehicle) they return object that I need, but my problem is when there is an object inside the object and It has a value it return a broken result: `{"id":34052,"modelID":1,"model":null,"vin":"xxx","engineNumber":"xxx","conductionSticker":"xxx","description":null,"cost":1.00,"date":"2010-10-10T00:00:00","profilePicture":null,"currentPlate":{"id":34051,"vehicleID":34052` without closing curly braces but when I set the object inside to null: `vehicle.CurrentPlate = null;` the result is fine

Comment: `{"id":34052,"modelID":1,"model":null,"vin":"xxx","engineNumber":"xxx","conductionSticker":"xxx","description":null,"cost":1.00,"date":"2010-10-10T00:00:00","profilePicture":null,"currentPlate":null}`

Comment: Again, it's not the response. It's possible your client, browser, whatever is mangling the response, but ASP.NET Core is returning valid JSON.